# Number of ways of distribution is

Tags: combinatorics

> out of $5$ apples, $10$ mangoes and $15$ oranges, any $15$ fruits distributed among $2$ persons, Then number of ways of distribution is

$(a)\; 66\;\;\;\; (b)\; 36\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; 60\;\;\;\; (d)$ None

What I try: number of ways is

$$\binom{30}{15}$$

but answer is different.

Please help me to solve it thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that $15$ pieces of fruit are distributed to each person or that a total of $15$ pieces of fruit are distributed to the two people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will look at all possible distributions.
We can give person $A$ $0,1,2,\dots,5$ apples and $0,1,2,\dots,10$ mangoes, such that the remaining amount will be filled with oranges.

For example, if person $A$ has $a\in\{0,1,2,\dots,5\}$ apples and $b\in\{0,1,2,\dots,10\}$ mangoes, than it must have $15-a-b$ oranges, such that person $A$ has a total of $15$ fruits.
Notice that $15-a-b$ will always be in the range $\{0,1,2,\dots,15\}$.
Furthermore person $B$ will get the remaining $15$ fruits.

This results in
$$
  6 \cdot 11 = 66
$$
possible distributions. Because person $A$ can choose $6$ different number of apples and $11$ different number of mangoes, than the rest is fixed.

Comment: Did not understand , what is the ammount person getting, please explain me.

Comment: @jacky I added an example, is this clear?

Comment: Correct but I don't think the answer is complete there are 66 ways of choosing 15 fruits from those three groups now the number of ways of sharing 66 fruits to two persons is (66+2-1) choose 66 that is 67 choose 66 which is 66 ... Just in case there were more than two persons

Comment: @arsenestein 67 choose 66 is 67 right?

Comment: @arsenestein your approach takes account with the order the distributions are picked, right?

Comment: Yeah 67 I mean just take a smaller number and verify

Comment: @BMath no not the order but actually who receives what... Except the question meant every person must receive at lest something and even in that case the answer is not 66...